# Do Android and iOS default media players support range byte-seek?

Tags: android, ios, video

I am working on a video service that delivers video to mobile platforms. I am currently thinking to use default system players to play video. I want to use progressive download over http. Do iOS and Android default media players support byte-seek? Can they request the video from a certain time when the file isn't loaded up to this time yet?

Comment: android is modular and open source and simply can't grant a default media player for both the AOSP and the OEM/Google release. What do you mean by default media player under Android ?

Comment: I mean the one that is a default system player. Like the one that comes with 4.1 android for nexuses for example.

Comment: there is no such thing in the Android world, you better provide your own media player if you want this assurance

Comment: @axis, what are you talking about? Any ROM has it

Comment: nope, but if you are sure about this go ahead

Comment: @axis could you please name at least 3 android phones that doesn't have it installed? I mean with official firmwares, ofcourse.

Comment: basically most of them, the OEM do not install them for basically 2 main reasons: A) patents and costs B) better and free alternatives on the market . All the Android that i have used since now do not have a video or media player, and again, Android is modular, even if you will find 3 device with a video player installed does not mean that you can assume that Android comes with a video player, this is not a vision about a real and opensource OS, i really don't see why it's so hard for you to think about an OS this way,

Comment: also there are many devices that lacks of "basic" apps like the Camera app, the Nexus 7 for example doesn't have a camera app by default; you just need to absorbe this concept, OS == nothing to do with the apps available.

Comment: Well, It's not hard for me to understand the basics of opensource OS distribution, it's hard for me to believe that there are real android phones that lack a default videoplayer out-of-the-box. I haven't seen one yet. All htc's, samsung, motorola and lg phones i've seen has it by default. I can't really believe that there is a phone with a ROM that will refuse to open a mp4-link in browser in a videoplayer, because there's no one installed.

Comment: @axis you are wrong, android supports many media types out of the box, you can find the full list [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) generally you play these files through the Gallery app that every androd phone has. Also the Nexus 7 does have a camera app, where are you getting your information?